# Microsoft.Ink mismatch between the processor architecture

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

When I run in debug mode on my machine (Visual Studio 2010), there are no problem, although the warning message appeared, but when I use Visual Studio 2012 the debug mode will not run, but it appears in the Task Manager Processes. It only runs on release mode in Visual Studio 2012.

How to solve the problem?

> There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project
>   being built "MSIL" and the processor architecture of the reference
>   "Microsoft.Ink, Version=6.1.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35", "AMD64". This mismatch may cause
>   runtime failures. Please consider changing the targeted processor
>   architecture of your project through the Configuration Manager so as
>   to align the processor architectures between your project and
>   references, or take a dependency on references with a processor
>   architecture that matches the targeted processor architecture of your
>   project.

Thank you.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10113532/visual-studio-c-c-solution-hitting-mismatch-between-processor-architecture

Comment: Actually, I don't think this is a duliplcate the other question refers to a mismatch between the main and an internal project. The solution there was to make both projects use the same setting for target cpu. In this case the question is about a mismatch between the main project and an external (.net!) library microsoft.ink and so a different solution is required.