# Adding DLL into 'Class Library Project': Mismatch between the processor architecture warning

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, dll

I am trying to convert a C# code (program.cs) into a DLL. This C# code uses another DLL, which is the DLL of [DreamCheeky Thunder Missile Launcher](http://www.dreamcheeky.com/thunder-missile-launcher). You can get the software from [here](http://files.dreamcheeky.com.s3.amazonaws.com/software/Thunder.exe) (just 1 mb) and the installation got this dll.

I created a `Class Library Project` under Visual Studio 2010 Professional C# category and added this DLL.

As soon as I added it, I got the following **warning**

> Warning   1   There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of
>   the project being built "MSIL" and the processor architecture of the
>   reference "USBLib", "x86". This mismatch may cause runtime failures.
>   Please consider changing the targeted processor architecture of your
>   project through the Configuration Manager so as to align the processor
>   architectures between your project and references, or take a
>   dependency on references with a processor architecture that matches
>   the targeted processor architecture of your project.  MissileLauncher

I am not familiar with windows specific programming, so do you mind letting me know why I am getting this and the solution?

Comment: It seems that you have dependency on a library that is built either for `x86` or `x64` and you're trying to build your project for `Any CPU`. At this point, I recommend to ignore this warning and if you notice some runtime-errors, recbuild your project for `x86` or `x64` respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple Google search finds us this:

[How do I fix the Visual Studio compile error, "mismatch between processor architecture"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10113532/how-do-i-fix-the-net-c-c-error-mismatch-between-processor-architecture)

Maybe apply the fixes that were proposed in there?