# Dynamics AX 2012 C# Compilation Warning

Tags: c#, dynamics-ax-2012

We receive the following error when compiling our C# Visual Studio project at some client sites.  The C# project is embedded in the AOT.

MSB3270: There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project being built "MSIL" and the processor architecture of the reference "Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.ManagedInterop", "x86". This mismatch may cause runtime failures.

Opening the project in Visual Studio, the target processor is set for "Any"   I know it is only a warning, but I'd like to resolve it if possible.

Any suggestions?

Thanks,

- Brad

Comment: [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10196549/1506223) might help.
It seems you have an x86 dependency.

Comment: We'll give it a shot.  Thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This was fixed by restarting the AOS.

No idea what was going on.