# Getting "a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project" on Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-8

I'm very new at Visual Studio 2012. I'm trying to connect my Windows 8 App to MySQL
on Visual Studio 2012 for my project. When I build solution, I get the following error:

> "There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the
>   project being built "MSIL" and the processor architecture of the
>   reference "System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=AMD64", "x86".
>   This mismatch may cause runtime failures. Please consider changing the
>   targeted processor architecture of your project through the
>   Configuration Manager so as to align the processor architectures
>   between your project and references, or take a dependency on
>   references with a processor architecture that matches the targeted
>   processor architecture of your project."

So I did some search on this and found this question on the site:
[How do I fix the Visual Studio compile error, "mismatch between processor architecture"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10113532/how-do-i-fix-the-net-c-c-error-mismatch-between-processor-architecture)

I tried to change according to their suggestion. I changed "Any CPU" to "x86" on "Platform" though the interface being described is different from mine. But this introduced me another error:

> "The base class or interface 'System.ComponentModel.Component' in
>   assembly 'System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' referenced by type
>   'System.Data.Common.DbConnection' could not be resolved"

Maybe, this has something to do with System.Data.dll that I need to put on "References" but I have no clue on how to fix this thing. What have I done wrong?

PS. I'm running on Windows 8.1 64-bit.

Comment: After changing the target platform did you clean the solution and rebuild?

Comment: Yeah, already did that.

Comment: If you have any dependent projects the dependencies have to be updated as well.

Comment: If I understand correctly, I suppose there's only one project with one cs file and one xaml file that I have added.