# Vitruvius Gesture not working, System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException

Tags: c#, wpf, kinect, kinect-sdk

Hi i recently came across vitruvius and wanted to implement their plugin on a wpf project to work with kinect gesture but was unable to even with their tutorials as shown below.

> https://vitruviuskinect.com/blog/

Had followed each step and downloaded their sample working code but would his this error message shown below.

[Click here to see the error message Image on Visual Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8BPTX.png)

The full error message is shown below.

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Warning       There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of
>   the project being built "MSIL" and the processor architecture of the
>   reference "LightBuzz.Vitruvius, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   processorArchitecture=AMD64", "AMD64". This mismatch may cause runtime
>   failures. Please consider changing the targeted processor architecture
>   of your project through the Configuration Manager so as to align the
>   processor architectures between your project and references, or take a
>   dependency on references with a processor architecture that matches
>   the targeted processor architecture of your project.  test2

The code written in the MainWindow.xaml.cs file

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Microsoft.Kinect;
using LightBuzz.Vitruvius;


namespace test2
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        KinectSensor _sensor;
        MultiSourceFrameReader _reader;
        GestureController _gestureController;


        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            _sensor = KinectSensor.GetDefault();

            if (_sensor != null)
            {
                _sensor.Open();

                _reader = _sensor.OpenMultiSourceFrameReader( FrameSourceTypes.Body);
                _reader.MultiSourceFrameArrived += Reader_MultiSourceFrameArrived;

                _gestureController = new GestureController();
                _gestureController.GestureRecognized += GestureController_GestureRecognized;
            }


        }



        void Reader_MultiSourceFrameArrived(object sender, MultiSourceFrameArrivedEventArgs e)
        {
            var reference = e.FrameReference.AcquireFrame();



            // Body
            using (var frame = reference.BodyFrameReference.AcquireFrame())
            {
                if (frame != null)
                {
                    Body body = frame.Bodies().Closest();

                    if (body != null)
                    {
                        _gestureController.Update(body);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        void GestureController_GestureRecognized(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
        {
            lbGesture.Content = e.GestureType.ToString();
        }

    }
}
```

Really hope someone can help solve this issue! Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use an assembly that was compiled for x64 (or rather told to generate 64bit code from the MSIL)....but your application is most probably targeting `x86`...(or is using `AnyCPU` and your running on a 32bit version of Windows).

Your project, and the assemblies you are referencing must resolve to the same "architecture".

Looking at the project code on github, it looks like the project files have been edited to explicity set 64bit references. This means, it will only work if you are on a 64bit machine, and using AnyCPU on your project, or x64 as the platform type.

See how someone has changed this x86 configuration to use x64.

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|x86'">
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
    <OutputPath>bin\x86\Release\</OutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

and it's only using a reference to a 64bit flavour of the kinect library.

```
<Reference Include="Microsoft.Kinect, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=AMD64">
```

If you want to have a 32bit app, then you need to use x86 as platform types, and you need to change that reference so it is 32bit.

see: [How do I fix the Visual Studio compile error, "mismatch between processor architecture"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10113532/how-do-i-fix-the-visual-studio-compile-error-mismatch-between-processor-archit)

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <Prefer32Bit>false</Prefer32Bit>
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
    <DocumentationFile>bin\Release\LightBuzz.Vitruvius.XML</DocumentationFile>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|x86'">
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <OutputPath>bin\x86\Debug\</OutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|x86'">
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
    <OutputPath>bin\x86\Release\</OutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Kinect, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=AMD64">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\..\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Kinect\v2.0-DevPreview1404\Assemblies\Microsoft.Kinect.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
```

Comment: Oh thanks! After i changed to x64 it worked fine now.